# Example of measure sequence

Tags: measure-theory

Si $(F_n)$ is a decreasing sequence in $\textbf{X}$ and if $\mu(F_1)<+\infty$ then
$\mu \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n\right)=\lim \mu (F_n)$
What happend when $\mu(F_1)=+\infty$?. I need an example

Answer (score 1):

Everything goes wrong. Take $F_n = \left]-\infty, -n\right] \cup \left[n,+\infty\right[$ for all $n\geq 1$, in $\Bbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure ${\frak m}$. We have $F_1 \supset F_2 \supset \cdots$.

Also, we have that $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}F_n = \varnothing$ and ${\frak m}(F_n) = +\infty$ for all $n\geq 1$. And finally: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} {\frak m}(F_n) = +\infty \neq 0 = {\frak m}\left(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}F_n\right).$$